# Excel throws #NAME? error when I put = in a cell

Tags: excel

I want to make a list with some documentation and in one cell I need to have the following syntax:

`=Same like ...`

but Excel automatically changes the display of the cell to

`#NAME?`

How can I tell Excel that I just want to display some text in a cell like this: `=Same like ...`

Comment: Enter `'= Same like` in the cell. But please post such questions to http://superuser.com in the future!

Comment: Why do you need to put an equals sign `=` in front of text? If it is just a sentence just type it into the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every cell content which starts with `=` is automatically interpreted as formula by Excel. If you need to enter a string starting with the equals sign, you have to tell Excel to interpret this cell as string and not as formula. Do so by prepending the string with a single quote (`'`), like this:

```
'= Same like
```